# Dasync.Collections ParallelForEachAsync runs only as a sync loop

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, parallel-processing, dasync.asyncenumerator

I am trying to make parallel http request to make my app run faster.
Below is my minimal reproduction code:

```
    List<Tuple<int, int>> chunks = CreateBlockListToProcess(startBlock, currentBlock);

    await Dasync.Collections.ParallelForEachExtensions.ParallelForEachAsync(chunks, async chunk =>
    {
       await GetLogs(chunk, tokens, wallets);
    }, maxDegreeOfParallelism: 5);
 


    private async Task GetLogs(Tuple<int, int> chunk, string[] tokens, List<string> wallets)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Sending request{chunk.Item1}");
        var newItems = await GetLogsAsync(chunk.Item1, chunk.Item2, tokens);

        if(newItems != null)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"done{chunk.Item1}");
        }
    }
```

Seems to be prety simple and should work, but when I run it I get this output:

[image]

The request is sent, program waits for response and only then starts processing next item from "chunks".

I would expect that it print 5 times almost at the same time

- [10:05:19 INF] Sending request0
- [10:05:19 INF] Sending request5000
- [10:05:19 INF] Sending request10000
- [10:05:19 INF] Sending request15000
- [10:05:19 INF] Sending request20000

and than the information done(..) when the request finish.

GetLogsAsync method is just simple method with awaited http request inside.

Comment: Is there a reason that you prefer the third-party [Dasync](https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable) API over the new (.NET 6) [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you replace the `await GetLogs(chunk, tokens, wallets);` with `await Task.Run(() => GetLogs(chunk, tokens, wallets));`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am working in a bigger team and it is not up to me to change project to .net 6. Sir, it started to work, thank you. Do you know why it can be?

Comment: It might be that the `GetLogsAsync` method, that you haven't included in the question, has a synchronous implementation despite its asynchronous contract. My guess is that the `Dasync` API doesn't parallelize the invocations of the asynchronous delegate, it parallelizes only the awaiting of the resulting `Task`s, and that's why the `Task.Run` helps by offloading the invocations to the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: as i can read in https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable/blob/master/src/Extensions/ParallelForEachExtensions.cs     ->  ParallelForEachAsync without a maxDegreeOfParallelism parameter will result in a synced execution

Answer (score 1):

Check the source code at https://code.citrite.net/projects/github.com:Dasync/repos/AsyncEnumerable/browse/src/Extensions/ParallelForEachExtensions.cs?at=49ff1de41cc818f6aa099ad646c600d950a6d79c#279

```
public static Task ParallelForEachAsync<T>(
        this IAsyncEnumerator<T> enumerator,
        Func<T, long, Task> asyncItemAction,
        int maxDegreeOfParallelism,
        bool breakLoopOnException,
        bool gracefulBreak,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (enumerator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enumerator));
        if (asyncItemAction == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(asyncItemAction));

        var context = new ParallelForEachContext(maxDegreeOfParallelism, breakLoopOnException, gracefulBreak, cancellationToken);

        Task.Run(
            async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var itemIndex = 0L;

                    while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        if (context.IsLoopBreakRequested)
                            break;

                        await context.OnStartOperationAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        if (context.IsLoopBreakRequested)
                        {
                            context.OnOperationComplete();
                            break;
                        }

                        Task itemActionTask = null;
                        try
                        {
                            itemActionTask = asyncItemAction(enumerator.Current, itemIndex);
                        }
                        // there is no guarantee that task is executed asynchronously, so it can throw right away
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.Data["ForEach.Index"] = itemIndex;
                            context.OnOperationComplete(ex);
                        }

                        if (itemActionTask != null)
                        {
                            var capturedItemIndex = itemIndex;
#pragma warning disable CS4014  // Justification: not awaited by design
                            itemActionTask.ContinueWith(
                                task =>
                                {
                                    Exception ex = null;
                                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                                    {
                                        ex = task.Exception;

                                        if (ex is AggregateException aggEx && aggEx.InnerExceptions.Count == 1)
                                            ex = aggEx.InnerException;

                                        ex.Data["ForEach.Index"] = capturedItemIndex;
                                    }

                                    context.OnOperationComplete(ex);
                                });
#pragma warning restore CS4014
                        }

                        itemIndex++;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    context.AddException(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    await enumerator.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    context.OnOperationComplete();
                }
            });

        return context.CompletionTask;
    }
```

`ParallelForEachExtensions.ParallelForEachAsync` submits a task to the ThreadPool and it expects the `asyncItemAction` to be a pure async function (no sync function call inside the function). Otherwise, the sync function inside `asyncItemAction` will block the thread somewhere. Dasync cannot get a chance to execute its code until the block operation completes.

Take a look at the following code snippet:

```
using Dasync.Collections;


public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start!");

        var myStrings = new List<string>
        {
            "test0",
            "test1",
            "test2",
            "test3",
            "test4",
            "test5",
            "test6",
            "test7",
            "test8",
            "test9"
        };

        await myStrings.ParallelForEachAsync(ProcessMessageAsync,  Environment.ProcessorCount);
    }

    public static async Task ProcessMessageAsync(string input)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Start processing Message: {input}");
        // await Task.Delay(1000);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"End processing Message: {input}");
    }
}
```

It yields:

```
Start!
Start processing Message: test0
End processing Message: test0
Start processing Message: test1
End processing Message: test1
Start processing Message: test2
End processing Message: test2
Start processing Message: test3
End processing Message: test3
Start processing Message: test4
End processing Message: test4
Start processing Message: test5
End processing Message: test5
Start processing Message: test6
End processing Message: test6
Start processing Message: test7
End processing Message: test7
Start processing Message: test8
End processing Message: test8
Start processing Message: test9
End processing Message: test9
```

But if you uncomment the line

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

You will see:

```
Start!
Start processing Message: test0
Start processing Message: test1
Start processing Message: test2
Start processing Message: test3
Start processing Message: test4
Start processing Message: test5
End processing Message: test5
End processing Message: test3
End processing Message: test4
End processing Message: test2
End processing Message: test0
Start processing Message: test6
Start processing Message: test7
Start processing Message: test8
Start processing Message: test9
End processing Message: test1
End processing Message: test9
End processing Message: test6
End processing Message: test7
End processing Message: test8
```

That's because the `Task.Delay` gives Dasync a chance to submit coroutines before the thread is blocked.